# Null pointer access in variable inside a for

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

In the lines marked with $ show the following message:

*Multiple markers at this line
    - Null pointer access: The variable InformeSalvaguardasAGR can only be null at this 
     location
    - Null pointer access: The variable InformeSalvaguardasAGR can only be null at this 
     location*

But i dont know why exactly, InformeAmenazasAGR is a superior variable and they can access. Why shows this message and how i can i make it correctly?

```
            List<Object> InformeAmenazasAGR = null;
            List<Object> InformeSalvaguardasAGR = null;
            try {
                Locale locale = (Locale)request.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY);
                if (locale == null){
                    locale = Locale.getDefault();
                }
                ResourceBundle recursos = ResourceBundle.getBundle(ProcopGlobals.FICHERO_MULTILENGUAJE,locale);
                manager = new AGRInformesManager();

                // EXTRAER TODAS LAS AMENAZAS.          
                InformeAmenazasAGR = manager.preparaInformeRiesgoActivos(idDimension, tipoActivo, idActivo, tipoActivoTexto, nombreActivo, recursos);

                for (int i = 0; i < InformeAmenazasAGR.size()-1; i++) {
                    String Amenaza = InformeAmenazasAGR.get(i).toString();
                    Amenaza = Amenaza.substring(1,3);
                    Object resultadoQuery = manager.SalvaguardaPorAmenaza(Amenaza);
                    if(resultadoQuery!= null){
    $                   InformeSalvaguardasAGR.add(resultadoQuery);
                    } else {

                    }                           
                }
                if (InformeSalvaguardasAGR != null) {
                    //Prueba
                    String informetexto =InformeSalvaguardasAGR.toString();
                }

            } catch( Exception e ) {
                log.error( "No fue posible generar el informe AGR para el Tipo: "+tipoActivo+" Activo: "+idActivo+" en Dimension: "+idDimension+".EX:" + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if( manager != null ) {
                    try {
                        manager.closeDAO();
                    } catch( Exception e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                manager = null;
            }
        }
    JSONArray JSonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSonArray.put(InformeSalvaguardasAGR);
    String InformeSalvasAGR = JSonArray.toString();
    InformeSalvasAGR = InformeSalvasAGR.substring(1, InformeSalvasAGR.length()-1);

    request.setAttribute("InformeAmenazasAGR", InformeSalvasAGR);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where you have initialize them ?InformeSalvaguardasAGR ,It's just interface you have to provide some implementation

Comment: Your list is initialized to null: `List<Object> InformeSalvaguardasAGR = null;` Replace this line by `List<Object> InformeSalvaguardasAGR = new ArrayList<Object>();`

Comment: Thank you @StephaneM, i did not see my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something happens at the `try-catch-finally` block, both `InformeSalvaguardasAGR` and `InformeAmenazasAGR` won't be initialized and remain `null`. In future if they are `null`, you can get `NPE` trying to call their methods. I suggest you to replace this:

```
List<Object> InformeAmenazasAGR = null;
List<Object> InformeSalvaguardasAGR = null;
```

with this:

```
List<Object> InformeAmenazasAGR = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> InformeSalvaguardasAGR = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is global it is never initialized. You cannot add to a list which is null. So initialize the list to :

```
List<Object> InformeSalvaguardasAGR = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

instead of

```
List<Object> InformeSalvaguardasAGR = null;
```